# PHP checkbox form - displaying values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a checkbox in my contact form and I don't seem to be able to display the values in the email being sent via php. I know this is probably an `isset` problem, but I cannot fix it to show whether the user has clicked the checkbox or not.

**Form:**

```
<script>
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
    _("mybtn").disabled = true;
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
    formdata.append( "b", _("b").value );
    formdata.append( "c", _("c").value );
    formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
    formdata.append( "s", _("s").value );
    formdata.append( "d", _("d").value );
    formdata.append( "p", _("p").value );
    formdata.append( "checkbox1", _("checkbox1").value );
    formdata.append( "checkbox2", _("checkbox2").value );
    formdata.append( "checkbox3", _("checkbox3").value );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "example_parser.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thanks '+_("n").value+', your message has been sent.</h2>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("mybtn").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send( formdata );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
  <p><input id="n" placeholder="First name" required></p>
  <p><input id="b" placeholder="Last name" required></p>
  <p><input id="c" placeholder="C Number"></p>
  <p><input id="n" placeholder="N Number"</p>
    <p><input id="d" placeholder="Date of birth"></p>
    <p><input id="p" placeholder="Postcode"></p>
    <label for="sex">I am </label>
    <select id="s" name="s">
      <option value="female">Female</option>
      <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <label>
        <p>
        <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1" id="checkbox1"> 
              data1</label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="1" id="checkbox2">
        data2</label>
      <br>
      <label>
       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="1" id="checkbox3">
        data3</label></p>
      <br>
  <p><input id="mybtn" type="submit" value="Submit Form"> <span id="status"></span></p>
</form>
```

**example_parser.php:**

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['b']) && isset($_POST['c']) && isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['s']) || isset($_POST['d']) || isset($_POST['p']) && isset($_POST['checkbox1']) || isset($_POST['checkbox2']) || isset($_POST['checkbox3']) ){
    $n = $_POST['n']; // HINT: use preg_replace() to filter the data
    $b = $_POST['b'];
    $c = $_POST['c'];
    $n = $_POST['n'];
    $s = $_POST['s'];
    $s = $_POST['d'];
    $s = $_POST['p'];
    $z = $_POST['checkbox1'];
    $y = $_POST['checkbox2'];
    $x = $_POST['checkbox3'];
    $to = "";   
    $from = "";
    $subject = 'Please help';
    $message = '<b>First Name:</b> '.$n.' <b>Last Name</b> '.$b.' <b>C Number</b> '.$c.' <b>N Number</b> '.$n.' <b>Date of Birth</d> '.$d.' <b>Postcode</b> '.$p.' <b>Sex</b> '.$s.' <b>Option1</b> '.$z.' <b>Option2</b> '.$y.' <b>Option3</b> '.$x.' <br><b>End of message, thank you</b> '.$n.' <p>'.$b.'</p>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "The server failed to send the message. Please try again later.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why don't you var_dump $_POST and look at what you got with the request?

Comment: Is the PHP above the content of `example_parser.php`?

Comment: You have a typo / syntax error here `<p><input id="n" placeholder="N Number"</p>`

Comment: also you have 2 inputs with `id="n"`

Comment: Ok - that sounds promising - where do I add it? to this line? <form id="my_form" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou thanks for spotting that

Comment: @PatrickQ yes it is example_parser.php

Comment: I would recommend that you give your inputs more semantic id's. It will make your debugging a lot easier.

Comment: Why don't you just give your input elements `name` attributes and then create your `FormData` object from the entire form element instead of creating it input-by-input?

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson. I am just getting started and learning every day so apologies for the errors.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, is the email actually sending, just without the values injected?  Or is the email not being sent at all?  And your `&&` and `||` logic is incredibly confusing and likely not what you want.  I suggest you add some parenthesis to help split up the parts.

Comment: Thanks for your help @PatrickQ. Sadly with my limited knowledge I don't quite follow what I am supposed to do... Do I still need to add POST method?

Comment: @PatrickQ yes it sends fine, all perfect, but with checkboxes it just displays 'Option1 1 Option2 1 Option3 1'

Comment: Wait, so all the other values show up fine?  This is just about the checkbox values?  What are you _expecting_ to see for the checkboxes?  What you're reporting is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: @PatrickQ yes, all values come through ok. it's just that the email triggered doesn't actually reflect what has been ticked - it brings up '1' as value to all of them, even if I only ticked one of them. All I need to see really is what has been selected, what the form is not doing as it is.

Comment: $to is empty....

Comment: @KarloKokkak yes sorry, took my email address out - email works fine. Apologies, I should have added a dummy one.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember not checked checkboxes are not sent with `POST`. In Your php script change

`$z = $_POST['checkbox1'];`

to

`$z = $_POST['checkbox1'] ? : 'not_checked_value';`

Additionally: You assigned different post values to this same variable (look at `$s`) - You are losing some post data.

Additionally 2: add `name` attributes to Your inputs in html - all data from forms are assigned to their names.

Additionally 3: Good practice is to name variables as their are should be, for example `$sex` or `$gender` would be better name than `$s` - You will quick get lost in that way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment bigwolk. Really good feedback and will start using name attributes and better variable names. I added $z = $_POST['checkbox1']?:'not_checked_value'; but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use `var_dump($_POST)` to see if that values comes with request.

Comment: do you have a link to a tutorial? I've been reading forums but I am not quite sure how to use it.

Comment: Just in Yours php script add `var_dump($_POST);` before
`if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) )....` - result will be in Yours js in `ajax.responseText` - in dev console in your browser You can see it too.

Comment: I added var_dump($_POST); and this is what I get. Again, one of the checkboxes was ticked but it isn't reflected in the values. array(9) { ["n"]=> string(4) "test" ["b"]=> string(4) "test" ["c"]=> string(4) "test" ["s"]=> string(6) "female" ["d"]=> string(4) "test" ["p"]=> string(4) "test" ["checkbox1"]=> string(8) "checkbox" ["checkbox2"]=> string(8) "checkbox" ["checkbox3"]=> string(8) "checkbox" } success

Comment: So, problem is in js. Take a look at `formdata.append( "checkbox1", _("checkbox1").value );` - probably `_("checkbox1").value ` isn't what You want/expect.

Comment: I've tried taking it off but it doesn't communicate the value at all...

Comment: @GlaPul Have you even looked at my answer?

Comment: @PatrickQ - yes, for some reason when I change var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
formdata.append( "b", _("b").value );
formdata.append( "c", _("c").value );
formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
formdata.append( "s", _("s").value );
formdata.append( "d", _("d").value );
formdata.append( "p", _("p").value );
formdata.append( "checkbox1", _("checkbox1").value );
formdata.append( "checkbox2", _("checkbox2").value );
formdata.append( "checkbox3", _("checkbox3").value ); with var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('my_form')); it won't send

Comment: @PatrickQ I can see that my problem is adding these manually, but replacing it with the one line code above prevents the form from working. If I remove ("checkbox1").value from the end, it doesn't communicate that with PHP form
formdata.append( "checkbox1", _("checkbox1").value );
formdata.append( "checkbox2", _("checkbox2").value );
formdata.append( "checkbox3", _("checkbox3").value );

Comment: @GlaPul - please ckeck in dev console in Your browser if `_("checkbox3").value` has value which You expected (value of checkbox). Maybe it has to be replaced by `_("checkbox3").checked ? 1:0`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why all your checkboxes are showing as checked even if they aren't is because you're manually adding all of the inputs regardless of whether they are checked or not.  There's no reason to be adding each input to your `FormData` individually.  Instead, add the entire form.  You'll just need to name your form inputs inline.

Replace

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
formdata.append( "b", _("b").value );
formdata.append( "c", _("c").value );
formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
formdata.append( "s", _("s").value );
formdata.append( "d", _("d").value );
formdata.append( "p", _("p").value );
formdata.append( "checkbox1", _("checkbox1").value );
formdata.append( "checkbox2", _("checkbox2").value );
formdata.append( "checkbox3", _("checkbox3").value );
```

with

```
var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('my_form'));
```

and update your inputs to have a `name` attribute

```
<input id="n" name="n" placeholder="First name" required>
```

It would be smart to have more sensible names, but I'll leave that up to you to decide if you want to change that.

I also suggest that you learn a framework like jQuery (or Angular, whatever you want).  They make using ajax a *lot* easier.

Further, I suggest that you clean up your `isset()` logic and add some parenthesis around the groups that you're trying to check.  I can't tell from what you have what you're really going for there, so I can't do that for you.

Comment: @GlaPul Did you make _all_ of the suggested changes?  You can't just change the javascript, you need to make changes to your HTML too.  You also have some HTML syntax errors that will be visible if you run your HTML through a validator or paste it into something like jsfiddle.